# How do I order by an integer column divided the time difference in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to write and algorithm that orders links by: Link # of points / time difference in seconds / # of rows

The only part that I'm having trouble with is the time difference part.

```
(Link.query
     .join(Point, (Point.link == Link.id))
     .group_by(Link.id)
     .filter(Link.visibility == 1)
     .order_by(((Link.points / (datetime.now() - Link.time).seconds) / func.count(Point.id)).desc()))
```

Comment: what's the trouble?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It returns: AttributeError: Neither 'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'seconds'

Comment: `datetime.now() - Link.time` is a SQL expression and does not have the attribute `seconds`. You need to find the equivalent SQL function that gives you the number of seconds in an interval.

Comment: Please provide the models or part of them in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: Well, you didn't provide any sample of your ORM, so I guessed one.*

I think you need to not mix up python date types with sql date types. You need to use functions from your database.

If using SQLite, you could use this order:

```
# only valid for sqlite
my_order = func.count(Link.points)/(functions.current_timestamp() - Link.time) / func.count(Point.id)
```

If using MySQL, you could use this order:

```
# only valid for MySQL
my_order = func.count(Link.points)/func.time_to_sec(func.timediff(functions.current_timestamp(), Link.time)) / func.count(Point.id)
```

Here is a full example using SQLite:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import datetime

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, types, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session, Session, relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy.schema import DefaultGenerator
from sqlalchemy.sql import functions, func

Base = declarative_base()

class Link(Base):
    __tablename__ = "link"
    id = Column(types.Integer, primary_key=True)
    visibility = Column(types.Integer, default=1)
    time = Column(types.DateTime, default=functions.current_timestamp())

    points = relationship("Point", backref="link")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Link(id=%r, visibility=%r, time=%r, points=[#%r])" % (self.id,
                                self.visibility, self.time, len(self.points))

class Point(Base):
    __tablename__ = "point"
    id = Column(types.Integer, primary_key=True)
    link_id = Column(types.Integer, ForeignKey('link.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point(id=%r, link_id=%r" % (self.id, self.link_id)


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

for i in range(10):
    time = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 31 - i)
    link = Link(time=time)
    for j in range(15 - i):
        link.points.append(Point())
    session.add(link)

my_order = (func.count(Link.points)
            / (functions.current_timestamp() - Link.time)
            / func.count(Point.id))


session.query(Link).join(Point).filter(Link.visibility==1)\
.group_by(Link.id).order_by(my_order.desc()).all()
```

It's possible to write a generic function that compiles differently according to SQL database, in order to do this, see [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/compiler.html#utc-timestamp-function).